# How to convert an affine matrix setup in a metric coordinate system to a pseudo web mercator System

Tags: coordinate-system, affine-transformation

I have an affine matrix (with rotation and translation), which is setup in a local metric coordinate system.

```
     1 0 0 10 
M =  0 1 0 15
     0 0 1 14
     0 0 0 1

webMercPoint = (20000, 1000, 0)

transformedWebMercPoint = webMercPoint*M
```

I want to convert this affine matrix to pseudo web mercator system, such that whenever I apply this to matrix to point in a pseudo mercator system, it works.

To convert the pseudo web mercator meter units, I setup a scale factor, which is basically

```
scaleFactor = 1/cos(latitude)
```

To convert the translation part, I can just scale up the translation part of the matrix, and that seems to work and the results are as I expect.

```
 1 0 0 10*scaleFactor 
 0 1 0 15*scaleFactor
 0 0 1 14*scaleFactor
 0 0 0 1
```

But as soon as I introduce rotation to this matrix, the results are wrong.

Do I have to do something more to cater for the rotation, my brains says that it should work, but it seems that the results are not as expected.

And I can confirm that if I convert the `webMercPoint` to metric coordinate system first and apply the transform without scaling, everything works correctly.
So it isn't the unscaled matrix that is wrong.

( and before anyone asks, I cannot always convert the `webMercPoint` to the metric coordinate system, as in certain cases the metric coordinate systems have a very small extent, and the large web mercator coordinates can be invalid, and the transform to metric system can be incorrect.)

Comment: Hi!, I don't understand your question. But in the affine transformation, the scale factor applies only to the rotation matrix.

Comment: I think I might have used the word scale factor more liberally here. I have a transform in meters, I want to apply it to a point in web mercator units. As there is a difference between web mercator units and meters depending upon the latitude, I want to change the units of the transform to web mercator units by multiplying it by a factor, not completely sure what I should do to the rotation part of the matrix.

Comment: Just multiply the rotation matrix by the scale factor, and apply the translation column without scaling it. If you computed the transformation matrix in a more liberally way than a scaled rotation and a translation, so feel free to liberally apply the scale factor in the same way as the transformation matrix was computed.